# Update db from Excel with Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: entity-framework-4

I'm new to EF 4.1 and try to move some code from to EF 4.1 (code first). Here is some background. I'm managing products for several companies, so I have a table "Product" with a column called "Company". I need to update (insert if not exist, otherwise update) this table from an Excel file containing products for a given company(let's say C1). Here is what I'm doing (using proprietary db access code and LINQ) :

- Retrieve all products for company C1 as a list of products
- For each product appearing in Excel:

  - Search the loaded list of products if the product from Excel exists already
  - If product does not exist then :
  - create new product instance
  - add product to database
  - add product to the list of loaded products
    Else
  - update product in database

That's pretty straightforward but converting it to EF 4.1 does not seem that easy:

I can easily retrieve and filter all products from the context. I can also easily search for the Excel product in the loaded list. If not present, I can create the product and add it to the context. But how to mimic my "caching" system where I add the newly added product to my list of product loaded in memory (Excel file can contains several times the same product) ? Also when change the entity state and when to do savechanges ?

Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a rough outline of how you can do this.

EF caches the loaded entities. You can use [Local](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696248%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) property to access it. This collection will be modified by EF when you add new entities.

```
context.Products.Where(p => p.Company == "C1").ToList();//force EF to load products

while(/*loop through excel file)
{
  var product = context.Products.Local.Where(p=> p.Id == excelProductId);
  if (product == null)
  {
     //insert
  }
  else
  {
    /update
  }
}

context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This "Local" property was exactly what I had been looking for. Perfect !